# Doing a limit and pushing all other entries into "Other"

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to do the following `LIMIT 10` query:

```
SELECT item, count(*) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY item 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

And then push all over values into an "Other" row (row 11 in the above case). Is it possible to do this in a single query without a join or something else? What I have now is:

```
SELECT IFNULL(t2.item, 'Other'), COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT item 
                 FROM table 
                 GROUP BY item 
                 ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
                 LIMIT 10) t2 ON (item)
GROUP BY t2.item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions and two level of aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN seqnum > 10 THEN 'Other' ELSE item END) as the_item,
       SUM(cnt) as cnt
FROM (SELECT item, COUNT(*) as cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table t
      GROUP BY item
     ) t
GROUP BY the_item
ORDER BY MAX(seqnum) DESC;
```

Comment: thanks, how would the performance of using a window different from the join?

Comment: @David542 . . . You would need to try this on your data, but I would expect this to be much faster than two complete aggregations of the original data.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will be more performant than Gordon's answer, but here's a hacky way using `CTE`

```
with a as
(select item, count(*) as cnt
 from t
 group by item
 order by cnt desc limit 0,10), --top ten rows

b as
(select item, count(*) as cnt
 from t
 group by item
 order by cnt desc limit 10,18446744073709551615) --all but top 10 rows
 
select item, cnt 
from a
union all
select 'other', sum(cnt) 
from b;
```